# using DATE_FORMAT in a SELECT statement

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using php + mysql to create a csv file. I'm having trouble using DATE_FORMAT in the SELECT statement. firstusedtime and lastusedtime should be formatted for example 01-19-2015 06:18 am instead of 2015-01-19 06:18:56.

```
mysql_connect("$dbhost", "$dbuser", "$dbpasswd") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("$dbname") or die(mysql_error());

$rows = mysql_query('SELECT whocsv, phonenumber, location, firstusedtime, lastusedtime, numbersonfile, totalchanges FROM phpbb_phonelist WHERE activenumber = 1');

// loop over the rows, outputting them
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows)) 

fputcsv($output, $row);
```

Comment: Why not post an attempted SQL statement that actually attempts to use DATE_FORMAT?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format Your format should be `'%m-%d-%Y %h:%i %p'` though you may need to wrap the output in `LOWER()` if you want `am` instead of `AM`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this for $rows

```
$rows = mysql_query("SELECT whocsv, phonenumber, location, DATE_FORMAT(firstusedtime,'%m-%d-%Y %h:%i %p') as firstusedtime, DATE_FORMAT(lastusedtime,'%m-%d-%Y %h:%i %p') as lastusedtime, numbersonfile, totalchanges FROM phpbb_phonelist WHERE activenumber = 1");
```

Comment: ah I needed to use " " instead of ''

Comment: Yeah that part I just copied and pasted from your code yeah the quotes around the whole string should be double quotes " because inside you have used single quotes unless you wish to escape them like so \'

Answer (score 1):

This should solve:

```
SELECT whocsv, phonenumber, location, date_format(firstusedtime, '%m-%d-%Y %h:%i %p') as firstusedtime, date_format(lastusedtime, '%m-%d-%Y %h:%i %p') as lastusedtime, numbersonfile, totalchanges FROM phpbb_phonelist WHERE activenumber = 1');
```

Google a little bit...
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: Not quite, that results in `01-19-03 17-34 pm`

Comment: And `%Y` instead of `%U` is needed.

Comment: heheh.. Tipo mistake :D